# If $f$ is analytics in $z_{0}$ ($z_{0}$ is a zero of order m). Show that $1/f$ has a pole of order m at z

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm solving the exercises of Churchill was unable to resolve this in particular, any help is welcome. 
 
9. If a function $f$ is analytics in $z_{0}$ and $z_{0}$ is a zero of ordem m of $f$, proves that the function  $1/f$ has a pole of order m in $z_{0}$

Thanks

Comment: Hint: $f(z) = (z-z_0)^m g(z)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}(z-z_{0})^{k}f(z)$ converge to nonzero value if and only if $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow z_{0}}(z-z_{0})^{-k}\frac{1}{f(z)}$ converge to nonzero value, by property of limit ($k$ integer, not necessarily positive).